# Context Service race condition

Tags: java, android, android-service

My application seems to be experiencing a race condition and I am unsure why. It only happens when I first open the application. According to the error the  static variable instance in MainActivity is null but I set the variable before I start the service. It almost seems that the service starts running before the onCreate finishes within the activity but I don't believe that is possible. Any ideas what is happening?

Error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer- 

java.lang.NullPointerException                                                              
at NetworkCalls.getRequestQueue(NetworkCalls.java:42)                                                             
at NetworkCalls.addToRequestQueue(NetworkCalls.java:48)                                                                     
at NetworkCalls.createLocationPost(NetworkCalls.java:72)                                                                   
at StaticMethods.handleWarnings(StaticMethods.java:84)                                                                    
at LocationService.checkInPost(LocationService.java:73)                                                                     
at LocationService$1.run(LocationService.java:66)                                                                     
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Networks Class

```
public class NetworkCalls {
    private static NetworkCalls singleton;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context warningCtx = WarningActivity.instance;
    private static Context mCtx = MainActivity.instance;

    private NetworkCalls() {
    }

    public static synchronized NetworkCalls getInstance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new NetworkCalls();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {

            //Problem here is that mCtx is null
            if(mCtx == null){
                Log.e("Error", "It's FUBAR");
            }else {
                Log.e("Error", "It's Okay");
            }
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    private <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void createLocationPost(LocationData locationData) {
        String url = "http://httpbin.org/post";
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Token", "key");

        JsonObjectRequest jsObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.i("NetworkCalls Successful", response.getJSONObject("json").toString());
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    Log.i("Parsing response", "Unable to get json string");
                }
                // On Response recieved
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("NetworkCalls Error", error.toString());
            }
        });
        addToRequestQueue(jsObj);
    }
```

Main acivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static MainActivity instance = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);


        instance = MainActivity.this;
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), QueuePostService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Context mCtx = MainActivity.instance;
```

This is initialized when the class is loaded. It takes the value of the field at that time, not when you subsequently use it.

That means that if it is `null` when the classloader loads `NetworkCalls`, it remains `null` until it is reassigned.

You would need to use `MainActivity.instance` instead of `mCtx` to get the field's current value.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I would not of thought about how the class loader was working and it was near impossible to trace the problem. Saved me hours of head bashing!

Comment: Don't think about how the class loader is loading: just remember that Java variables are values, not references, so subsequent changes to the "referred to" variable are not reflected in the "referencing" variable.